# Touchpad quit working after update

Tags: settings, mouse, touchpad

A couple of days ago I updated elementary OS through the software updater, and after restarting the laptop, the touchpad no longer worked. The mouse would not move from the center of the screen. First, I verified I did not accidentally turn off the touchpad with the hotkey. I was able to get the touchpad to work by running the following commands:

```
sudo modprobe -r psmouse
sudo modprobe psmouse
```

This allowed me to regain control of the mouse, however, two finger scrolling does not work. I went to the touchpad settings and checked the two finger scroll checkbox, but the change is not saved after exiting settings. Once I open the touchpad menu up again, the two finger scroll checkbox is still unchecked. Finally, the commands above are not persistent after a restart.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

First we are going to check if the touchpad is really using the settings it should.
Open a terminal and type: `xinput`
Look for your touchpad and remember the id number. Then type: `xinput list-props`.
If a setting is set to 0 it means it's unchecked. If you want to set it to 1 just type
`xinput set-prop [id] [setting number] 1` .
The same applies if you want to set it to 0. Finally, to make those settings persistent you need to create a .conf file. But to do so I need to know what files you have inside `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d`

Basically it would be completing this file:

```
Section "InputClass"
Identifier "touchpad"
Driver "synaptics" #maybe other driver
MatchIsTouchpad "on"
    Option #[option here]
EndSection
```

Answer (score 1):

Had exactly the same problem. When You type `xinput` You can notice, that your touchpad is now recognized as PS2 mouse. Try to reinstall the driver, it should fix this. Just check if you need Elantech/Synaptic/etc driver, remove it with

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge <your driver package>
```

And reinstall it with

```
sudo apt-get install <your driver package>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi all i have upgraded my kernel using linux kernel updater from here https://github.com/bkw777/mainline

kernel version in my elementary os is now 5.11, and everything works including my touchpad and display drivers

Answer (score 0):

This might sound silly, but it worked for me until I found an updated driver for my laptop's track pad. But once you boot if your mouse isn't working, try suspending your laptop and resuming.

No guerentees, and I've not a clue why it was working this way, but it worked for me.